# How to download a 33gb file from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, download, file-sharing, file-transfer

I am trying to download a 33,4gb 'anybody with a link' file from Google Drive but it always gets interrupted at around two thirds way through, claiming "network issue", and on resume "no permission", every time.

I'm guessing there is a quota of about 20gb per download, since smaller 11-18gb files have downloaded fine, one right after another. I have tried pausing the file halfway through and continuing hours later but by then it refuses to resume.

I have also tried a few browser extension download managers but none of them display any links for any of the files in the shared directory, as if not compatible with google drive.

I only have 15gb space in my account so I can't do the "copy file" trick for files this large. Any solutions welcome. PC time zone change or network change does not work either, so not a duplicate question.